# Why take the derivative when using slsqp algoritm?

Tags: machine-learning, python, optimization

I'm looking at the documentation for scipy's optimize minimize module as seen [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize).

The problem supposes a function as well as two constraints.

Objective Funtion:

```
f(x, y) = 2 x y + 2 x - x^2 - 2 y^2
```

subject to an equality and an inequality constraints defined as:

```
x^3 − y = 0
y - 1 ≥ 0
```

From here the documentation proceeds to take these steps:

```
def func(x, sign=1.0):
...     """ Objective function """
...     return sign*(2*x[0]*x[1] + 2*x[0] - x[0]**2 - 2*x[1]**2)
>>> def func_deriv(x, sign=1.0):
...     """ Derivative of objective function """
...     dfdx0 = sign*(-2*x[0] + 2*x[1] + 2)
...     dfdx1 = sign*(2*x[0] - 4*x[1])
...     return np.array([ dfdx0, dfdx1 ])
Note that since minimize only minimizes functions, the sign parameter is introduced to multiply the objective function (and its derivative) by -1 in order to perform a maximization.
```

**My question is:** Why are they taking the derivative at all?

Scipy is a module of python, which is a programming language afterall, why do we need to provide that for the module; it seems uncharacteristic of a language that is usually very intuitive and elegant. Here are some of my guesses thus far:

- If you were optimizing by hand, then you could imagine they wanted to
  set the derivative to zero and solve for x, but that does not seem to
  be what they are doing, so maybe this is not the reason.
- Are they just showing that step for robustness/clarity?
- Or perhaps the derivative is needed because they intend to maximize
  the function using the minimize module, which requires a bit of
  craftiness?

Answer (score 1):

The gradient is needed for the minimization method they are exposing further into your link (SLSQP).
The gradient can be estimated via some methods, but these methods are likely less optimal than giving the actual formula for the gradient.
Thus, providing a callable derivative function to the minimization method is likely done to improve convergence.

Comment: That's something I didn't know, thanks for pointing that out. If SLSQP is usually less optimal than the gradient, what is the niche use case for SLSQP? When we don't know or can't calculate the gradient? Or is it just lower on the optimization totem pole so to speak?

Comment: @ArashHowaida Oh, my mistake, i didn't make this clear : the "likely less optimal" was reffering to the methods used to estimate the gradients, not to SLSQP.
I unfortunately have little experience comparing the different optimization methods, maybe [the documentation for minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)'s links to the different methods can help you?